# How to execute only parts of a function?

Tags: python

I have defined a class which contains some basic matrix functions. My function for transposing a matrix looks like this:

```
def transpose(self):
    '''
    Transpose a matrix.
    '''
    C = Z ## creating a new zero matrix
    for i in range(0, self.rows):
        for j in range(0, self.cols):
            C.matrix[i][j] = self.matrix[j][i]

    ## printing the resultant matrix
    C.show()
    return C
```

So when I call this function from the interpreter, it prints the result after execution (because of the `show()` function).

However, when I call this function from another function in the same class, I don't want the matrix to be printed, that is, I don't want the `C.show()` part to execute.

Is there any way to do this? I was thinking on the lines of `__name__ == "__main__"` but that doesn't really apply here it seems.

Comment: Why is C.show needed anyways? This is tightly coupling your function. Can't you print the result after the function returns only where you want to?

Comment: Do you mean like adding a default parameter like "print_me=False" to the function and explicitly setting it to "True" when you want to print (I occasionally do this when developing/debugging)?

Comment: Looks like @Ben had the same idea.

Comment: The answers have shown you better ways to structure your code, but the simple answer to your question is "No".  The only way to run just part of a function is to change the function so it includes some kind of conditional check, in which case it's not really the same function and you might as well rewrite it completely to separate out the part you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another, default, parameter to the function and put the print in an `if`:

```
def transpose(self, print_matrix=True):
    '''
    Transpose a matrix.
    '''
    C = Z ## creating a new zero matrix
    for i in range(0, self.rows):
        for j in range(0, self.cols):
            C.matrix[i][j] = self.matrix[j][i]

    ## printing the resultant matrix
    if print_matrix:
        C.show()
    return C
```

As it has a default value you don't need to change any current method calls, but you can add another parameter to your new one. Call it as `transpose(False)`, if you don't want to print.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the calculation and display are both coupled into the same function. In general, tight coupling like this is considered undesirable. Why? Well, you are seeing the problem now, you can't do one part of the function without the other.

Now I could give you crazy answers about how to only print when called from the interpreter, but I would be encouraging bad code. Instead, we should decouple this function into two different function.

Decoupling is simple, take the two different things your code is doing -- printing and calculating -- and separate them into two different functions.

```
def transpose(self):
    '''
    Transpose a matrix.
    '''
    C = Z ## creating a new zero matrix
    for i in range(0, self.rows):
        for j in range(0, self.cols):
            C.matrix[i][j] = self.matrix[j][i]

    return C

def transposeAndPrint(self):
    C = transpose(self)
    C.show()
```

Now you can call transposeAndPrint when you need to print, and transpose when you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Of course I could tell you to add an extra parameter but that won't change the fact that a transpose function should not do printing (except for debug).

```
def transpose(self):
    '''
    Transpose a matrix.
    '''
    C = Z ## creating a new zero matrix
    for i in range(0, self.rows):
        for j in range(0, self.cols):
            C.matrix[i][j] = self.matrix[j][i]

    return C
```

And somewhere else, where you need it:

```
o.transpose()
o.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use Python's logging module.  You can set multiple logging levels, which are intended for just this type of situation. In this case, you could make the show function output at the DEBUG level, which you can then easily turn on or off as need be.

See:

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html